# How to assign zero numbers when generate randint?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I want to generate random numbers like

```
import random
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randint(8,size=(5,126))
```

What I want is when a list generates 126 random numbers between 0 to 7, assign 0 count as I want.
For example, maybe this code generates 630 random numbers.
I want to have 5 rows with 590 count zero, and 40 count one to seven in 630 random numbers.

How could I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want a zero-inflated random distribution.  One way to do that would be to sample from a bernoulli distribution, and if you get 0 return 0, and if you get 1 then assign the result of another random distribution, but you haven't told us which one.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want exact count for EVERY integer**: Here is a way to do it for a toy example of 10 zeros, 5 ones and 5 twos and a shape of `(4,5)`. You can change the numbers and their counts and shape to your choice):

```
#create integers in the counts you want and stack them into single 1-D array
A = np.hstack((np.zeros(10),np.ones(5),np.ones(5)*2))
#randomly shuffle them
np.random.shuffle(A)
#reshape to your desire
A = A.reshape(4,5)
```

Sample output:

```
[[2. 0. 1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 2.]
 [1. 2. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]]
```

**If you want exact count ONLY FOR 0s**: Per @FBruzzesi's comment, here is a way to do it for a toy example of 10 zeros, and 10 ones/twos and a shape of `(4,5)`. You can change the numbers and their counts and shape to your choice):

```
#create integers in the counts you want and stack them into single 1-D array
A = np.hstack([np.zeros(10),np.random.randint(1,3,size=10)])
#randomly shuffle them
np.random.shuffle(A)
#reshape to your desire
A = A.reshape(4,5)
```

Sample output:

```
[[1. 2. 1. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: For completeness  and to address directly the op question you can use `A = np.hstack([np.zeros(590), np.random.randint(1, 8,size=40)]).reshape(5,126)`

Comment: @FBruzzesi thank you. Question's text is a bit unclear. I assumed OP wants exact count for each integer. But if it is only exact count for 0s, your comment is correct. Adding it to answer :)

Comment: I assumed they are 40 random integers between 1 and 7 just because you cannot divide 40 by 7 :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(1, 8, (5, 126))
idx = np.random.choice(range(arr.size), 590, replace=False)
arr[np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape)] = 0

print (np.sum(arr == 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this in one step but you can try the following procedure:
Generate 126 random integers in range [0-7] (included).

Then you count the number of zeroes in the array (it should be around 16 ~ 126/8).

Now you can randomly set some values (that are not zeros) at 0 until you reach the desired number by iterating through the array.